# What style of lager is Corona? And what other beers are similar?

Tags: style, lager, classification

Corona Extra is a Mexican beer that is very popular (in Australia anyway). Most people seem to like it for it's drinkability, and suitability for enjoyment in hot weather.

Is there a name for this style of lager? Eg; I don't think it's a pilsener or dark lager.

And what other beers are in the same style?

Comment: Corona Extra _Dry_? I found a link to a beer store in [Japan](http://www.nisekowinesupply.com/showProduct/Beer+and+Mixers/Beer/BEER09003/Corona+Extra+Dry+330ml+6+bottle+pack) but it looks like the regular Corona Extra bottle. Nothing else comes up in Google or on Corona'a site.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I must have confused it with the name of Tooheys Extra Dry - another well known beer in Australia. I have fixed the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The BJCP classifies Corona Extra as a [Premium American Lager](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style01.php#1c), being, clear, yellow, not hoppy but with a little more body than a light.

Assuming 'dry' isn't some radically different beer, the category would probably still be correct. BJCP draft guidelines (not official) consider putting Asahi Super Dry and Corona Extra in  2A 'International Pale Lagers' which is '*Loosely derived from original Pilsner-type lagers....*'

[1MB PDF](http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2014%20BJCP%20Style%20Guidelines%20(DRAFT).pdf) if you want to read the draft.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and helpful answer. The links to the website are particularly useful - I hadn't been aware of  that site before.

Answer (score -2):

Corona is a very famous, international beer consisting of corn. It's made by a starchy product, and that's why we use to lemon wedges at the time of serving: in order to disguise the starchy taste.

Comment: Hi Akash, and welcome to beer.SE!  the question is specifically about the name of style.   While the information in your answer is useful, it is really only supplemental.  Can you address the question as well?